# Java 8 stream's .min() and .max(): why does this compile?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Note: this question originates from a dead link which was a previous SO question, but here goes...

See this code (**note: I do know that this code won't "work" and that `Integer::compare` should be used -- I just extracted it from the linked question**):

```
final ArrayList <Integer> list 
    = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list.stream().max(Integer::max).get());
System.out.println(list.stream().min(Integer::min).get());
```

According to the javadoc of [`.min()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) and [`.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-), the argument of both should be a `Comparator`. Yet here the method references are to static methods of the [`Integer`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class.

So, why does this compile at all?

Comment: Note that it doesn't work properly, it should be using `Integer::compare` instead of `Integer::max` and `Integer::min`.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I know that; note how I said before the code extract "I know, it is absurd"

Comment: I wasn't trying to correct you, i'm telling people in general. You made it sound as if you thought that the part that is absurd is that methods of `Integer` are not methods of `Comparator`.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Let me explain what is happening here, because it isn't obvious!

First, [`Stream.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) accepts an instance of [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so that items in the stream can be compared against each other to find the minimum or maximum, in some optimal order that you don't need to worry too much about.

So the question is, of course, why is [`Integer::max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#max-int-int-) accepted?  After all it's not a comparator!

The answer is in the way that the new lambda functionality works in Java 8.  It relies on a concept which is informally known as "single abstract method" interfaces, or "SAM" interfaces.  The idea is that any interface with one abstract method can be automatically implemented by any lambda - or method reference - whose method signature is a match for the one method on the interface.  So examining the [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface (simple version):

```
public Comparator<T> {
    T compare(T o1, T o2);
}
```

If a method is looking for a `Comparator<Integer>`, then it's essentially looking for this signature:

```
int xxx(Integer o1, Integer o2);
```

I use "xxx" **because the method name is not used for matching purposes**.

Therefore, both `Integer.min(int a, int b)` and `Integer.max(int a, int b)` are close enough that autoboxing will allow this to appear as a `Comparator<Integer>` in a method context.

Comment: or alternatively: `list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).max().get()`.

Comment: @assylias You want to use `.getAsInt()` instead of `get()` though, as you are dealing with an `OptionalInt`.

Comment: ... when what we are only trying is to provide a custom comparator to a `max()` function!

Comment: It's worth noting that this "SAM Interface" is actually called a "Functional Interface" and that looking at the `Comparator` documentation we can see that it's decorated with the annotation `@FunctionalInterface`. This decorator is the magic that allows `Integer::max` and `Integer::min` to be converted into a `Comparator`.

Comment: @ChrisKerekes the decorator `@FunctionalInterface` is principally for documentation purposes only, as the compiler can happily do this with any interface with one single abstract method.

Answer (score 119):

`Comparator` is a *functional interface*, and `Integer::max` complies with that interface (after autoboxing/unboxing is taken into consideration). It takes two `int` values and returns an `int` - just as you'd expect a `Comparator<Integer>` to (again, squinting to ignore the Integer/int difference).

However, I wouldn't expect it to do the right thing, given that `Integer.max` doesn't comply with the *semantics* of `Comparator.compare`. And indeed it doesn't really work in general. For example, make one small change:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    list.add(-i);
```

... and now the `max` value is -20 and the `min` value is -1.

Instead, both calls should use `Integer::compare`:

```
System.out.println(list.stream().max(Integer::compare).get());
System.out.println(list.stream().min(Integer::compare).get());
```

Comment: I know about the functional interfaces; and I know why it gives the wrong results. I just wonder how on earth the compiler didn't yell at me

Comment: @fge Because it is technically correct, but I wonder if there is a way that this could be prevented?

Comment: @fge: Well was it the unboxing you were unclear about? (I haven't looked into exactly that part.) A `Comparator<Integer>` would have `int compare(Integer, Integer)`... it's not mind-boggling that Java allows a method reference of `int max(int, int)` to convert to that...

Comment: @fge: Is the compiler supposed to know the semantics of `Integer::max`?  From its perspective you passed in a function that met its specification, that's all it can really go on.

Comment: @fge: In particular, if you understand *part* of what's going on, but are intrigued about one specific aspect of it, it's worth making that clear in the question to avoid people wasting their time explaining the bits you already know.

Comment: I think the underlying problem is the type signature of `Comparator.compare`. It should return an `enum` of `{LessThan, GreaterThan, Equal}`, not an `int`. That way, the functional interface wouldn't actually match and you would get a compile error. IOW: the type signature of `Comparator.compare` doesn't adequately capture the semantics of what it means to compare two objects, and thus other interfaces which have absolutely nothing to do with comparing objects accidentally have the same type signature.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This is definitely worthy of an answer in its own right. You've summed it up perfectly. If you post this as an answer then I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 19):

This works because `Integer::min` resolves to an implementation of the `Comparator<Integer>` interface.

The method reference of `Integer::min` resolves to `Integer.min(int a, int b)`, resolved to `IntBinaryOperator`, and presumably autoboxing occurs somewhere making it a `BinaryOperator<Integer>`.

And the `min()` resp `max()` methods of the `Stream<Integer>` ask the `Comparator<Integer>` interface to be implemented.
Now this resolves to the single method `Integer compareTo(Integer o1, Integer o2)`. Which is of type `BinaryOperator<Integer>`.

And thus the magic has happened as both methods are a `BinaryOperator<Integer>`.

Comment: It's not entirely correct to say that `Integer::min` implements `Comparable`. It is not a type that can implement anything. But it is evaluated into an object which implements `Comparable`.

Comment: `Comparator<Integer>` is a single-abstract-method (aka "functional") interface, and `Integer::min` fulfills its contract, so the lambda can be interpreted as this. I don't know how you see BinaryOperator coming into play here (or IntBinaryOperator, either) – there is no subtyping relationship between that and Comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the information given by David M. Lloyd one could add that the mechanism that allows this is called *target typing*.

The idea is that the type the compiler assigns to a lambda expressions or a method references does not depend only on the expression itself, but also on where it is used.

The target of an expression is the variable to which its result is assigned or the parameter to which its result is passed.

Lambda expressions and method references are assigned a type which matches the type of their target, if such a type can be found.

See the [Type Inference section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) in the Java Tutorial for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error with an array getting the max and the min so my solution was:

```
int max = Arrays.stream(arrayWithInts).max().getAsInt();
int min = Arrays.stream(arrayWithInts).min().getAsInt();
```