# I use Guava's immutable collections (compiled for Java 6) and a Java 8 JRE, can I use the new stream interface?

Tags: java, collections, guava, java-8

I use Guava and in particular their immutable collections (`ImmutableList`, `ImmutableSet`).

But Guava is compiled for Java 6. If I use Java 8, can I use `.stream()` with them?

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can.

The `.stream()` method, which is defined in the `Collection` interface, [has a default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--). And so do, for that matter, [`.parallelStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) and [`.spliterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#spliterator--). And both `List`s and `Set`s "are" `Collection`s.

And it doesn't end there since you can also use [`Map`'s `.forEach()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) on Guava's `ImmutableMap`s as well. `Map` does have other default operations, but they mutate the map, and Guava's immutable collections/maps are... Well...

Note that more generally, **each time an interface's method has a default implementation, it *will* be mentioned in the javadoc, since the method's return type will be preceded with the `default` keyword**.

Some sample, very crude code which works and makes use of that (along with the concept of Single Abstract Method used in lambdas, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561614/java-8-streams-min-and-max-why-does-this-compile) for more details):

```
ImmutableSet.of(23, 2389, 19).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

(`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and its [`.println()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) signature is the same as that of a [`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html))

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact, `ImmutableList` implements `Collection` and `Iterable`, which are interfaces provided by `Java 8`, having default implementations for the methods you have enumerated, the answer you gave is not much a surprise, right?

Perhaps the question should be restated as: does `ImmutableList` implement `Collection` and `Iterable`? Because if it does, all default methods provided by `Java 8` are usable. In particular: `.stream()`, `.parallelStream()` and `.spliterator()`.

But then the answer would require only a lookup into the JavaDoc provided by [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), which is not a big deal either.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point at all. Is that _so_ obvious that `Collection` has a default method for `.stream()`? No. I didn't even know it before I checked.

Comment: What is more, this is a good foray into what `default` in interfaces can really do for you; I am sure that when the time comes, Google will override this implementation with a custom one which is faster for these particular `Collection`s.