# Static methods in java interface

Tags: java, interface, static-methods

As far as I know you cannot declare static methods in interface body. However, accidentally I found peculiar piece of code on http://docs.oracle.com/ site. Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Namelly

```
public interface TimeClient 
{
void setTime(int hour, int minute, int second);
void setDate(int day, int month, int year);
void setDateAndTime(int day, int month, int year,
                           int hour, int minute, int second);
LocalDateTime getLocalDateTime();

static ZoneId getZoneId (String zoneString) {
    try {
        return ZoneId.of(zoneString);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.err.println("Invalid time zone: " + zoneString +
            "; using default time zone instead.");
        return ZoneId.systemDefault();
    }
}

default ZonedDateTime getZonedDateTime(String zoneString) {
    return ZonedDateTime.of(getLocalDateTime(), getZoneId(zoneString));
    }
}
```

this `interface` has a `static` method `getZoneId`

I am lost... could anyone explain please

Comment: You _can_ declare static methods in interfaces starting with Java 8. Note also the `getZoneDateTime()` method (virtual extension method, also new in Java 8).

Comment: Please read this http://marioosh.5dots.pl/2014/02/12/java-8-default-and-static-methods-in-interfaces.html

Comment: Haven't you see new feature list of Java 8 ? check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 8 now has the idea of "default" method implementations in interfaces:

http://blog.hartveld.com/2013/03/jdk-8-13-interface-default-method.html

Comment: well everybody answered correctly to my question. You were the first one though.

Comment: Not really, there's a difference between default and static methods, so let's not confuse those (and other users). This was maybe a good pointer, but not a correct answer.

Comment: @virgo47 you're right, I'm not sure what I'm doing here. I looked to see if the question had originally referenced default methods but it didn't. I will delete this. Er, can't delete it as it's accepted :(

Answer (score 15):

You are the witness of two new features in Java 8 here:

- static methods in interfaces,
- virtual extension methods.

In the code sample you provide, `getZoneId()` illustrates the first novelty, and `.getZoneDateTime()` the second one.

The second one in particular is what has allowed the `Collection` interface to be extended with supplementary methods such as `.stream()`, for example, *without* breaking backwards compatibility. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660268/i-use-guavas-immutable-collections-compiled-for-java-6-and-a-java-8-jre-can) for an illustration.

The first one allows to avoid writing "method bags" classes which often exist only to provide utility static methods over interfaces. One such example would be [Guava's `Functions` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html) (not to be mixed with Java 8's `Function` which it basically stole from Guava, along with `Predicate` and a few others)

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Java 8 you can do this. The [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) that your snippet came from (which has been updated for Java 8) says it best:

> The interface body can contain abstract methods, default methods, and static methods. An abstract method within an interface is followed by a semicolon, but no braces (an abstract method does not contain an implementation). Default methods are defined with the `default` modifier, and static methods with the `static` keyword. All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly public, so you can omit the public modifier.

Or from Java 8's [JLS section 9.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> A default method is a method that is declared in an interface with the `default` modifier; its body is always represented by a block. It provides a default implementation for any class that implements the interface without overriding the method. Default methods are distinct from concrete methods, which are declared in classes.
>
> ...
>
> An interface can declare static methods, which are invoked without reference to a particular object.

Answer (score 5):

From Java Language Specification (Java SE 8 Edition): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4

> An interface can declare static methods, which are invoked without reference to a particular object.

Answer (score 4):

in Java 8, interfaces can have static methods, as well as override-able methods with a default implementation. They still can't have instance fields though. These features are part of the lambda expression support, and you can read more about them in Part H of. [JSR 335](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335)