# Java 8 streams, why does this compile part 2... Or what is a method reference, really?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

OK, the first question in this "series" was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561614/java-8-streams-min-and-max-why-does-this-compile).

Now, here is another case:

```
Arrays.asList("hello", "world").stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This compiles, and works...

OK, in the last question, static methods from a *class* were used.

But now this is different: `System.out` is a `static` field of `System`, yes; it is also a `PrintStream`, and a `PrintStream` has a `println()` method which happens to match the signature of a `Consumer` in this case, and [a `Consumer` is what `forEach()` expects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

So I tried this...

```
public final class Main
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        Arrays.asList(23, 2389, 19).stream().forEach(new Main()::meh);
    }

    // Matches the signature of a Consumer<? super Integer>...
    public void meh(final Integer ignored)
    {
        System.out.println("meh");
    }
}
```

And it works!

This is quite a different scope here, since I initiate a new instance and can use a method reference right after this instance is constructed!

So, is a method reference really *any* method which obeys the signature? What are the limits? Are there any cases where one can build a "@FunctionalInterface compatible" method which *cannot* be used in a `@FunctionalInterface`?

Comment: You should really read the [State of Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) starting at Section 8: Method References

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising, since you can do `new Main().meh(42)`

Comment: Should probably have used the "Reward existing answer" bounty reason instead of "Draw attention". No biggie, though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The syntax of method references is defined in [JLS #15.13](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). In particular it can be of the form:

> `Primary :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`

Where [`Primary` can be, among other things,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary) a:

> `ClassInstanceCreationExpression`

so yes, your syntax is correct. A few other interesting examples:

```
this::someInstanceMethod    // (...) -> this.someInstanceMethod(...)
"123"::equals               // (s) -> "123".equals(s)
(b ? "123" : "456")::equals // where b is a boolean
array[1]::length            // (String[] array) -> array[1].length()
String[]::new               // i -> new String[i]
a.b()::c                    // (...) -> a.b().c(...)
```

By the way, since you mention static methods, it is interesting to note that you can't create a static method reference from an instance:

```
class Static { static void m() {} }
Static s = new Static();

s.m(); //compiles
someStream.forEach(s::m); //does not compile
someStream.forEach(Static::m); //that's ok
```

Comment: Seems like I have a lot to learn... Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

From the [State of Lambda](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html)

> **Kinds of method references**
>
> There are several different kinds of method references, each with
>   slightly different syntax:
>
> - A static method (`ClassName::methName`)
> - An instance method of a particular object (`instanceRef::methName`)
> - A super method of a particular object (`super::methName`)
> - An instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type (`ClassName::methName`)
> - A class constructor reference (`ClassName::new`)
> - An array constructor reference (`TypeName[]::new`)

Answer (score 3):

Saying this:

```
something(new Main()::meh);
```

Is approximately equivalent to saying this:

```
Main x = new Main();
something(() -> x.meh());
```

Or this:

```
final Main x = new Main();
something(new Whatever() {
    public void meh(Integer ignored) {
        x.meh();
    }
}
```

The new instance is "captured" and used in the new lambda instance which was implicitly created from the method handle.