# How to use lambdas for interfaces with multiple methods?

Tags: java, oop, lambda, java-8

Is there a way to use lambdas if the target class has more than one interface methods? Or do you just have to use an anonymous inner class in that case?

Comment: You mean, in a same class, you have two methods potentially "implementing the interface"? Then use a method reference

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663112/java-8-streams-while-does-this-compile-part-2-or-what-is-a-method-reference) also; what you can actually use as a "lambda" is... Broad.

Comment: You can use lambda expressions as a replacement for anonymous inner class implementations that use *functional interfaces*. Functional interfaces can only have one explicitly declared abstract method.

Answer (score 25):

No, there isn't. If I understood your question correctly you'd want to use lambdas for interfaces with more than one abstract method. In that case the answer is negative:

> **A functional interface is any interface that contains only one
>   abstract method**. (A functional interface may contain one or more
>   default methods or static methods.) Because a functional interface
>   contains only one abstract method, you can omit the name of that
>   method when you implement it. To do this, instead of using an
>   anonymous class expression, *you use a lambda expression* [...]

Read it up there: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: In addition to the quote... There can be **more than one** abstract method, if these methods match those implemented by Object, leaving only one abstract method unimplemented. This case is a bit surprising to discover.

Comment: @uvsmtid Thanks for adding that. It clarified exactly what I was trying to answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to directly create a multi-method object with a lambda.

But, you can use a **work-around to solve the problem** in a pretty neat way:

Use a util method that takes a number of single-method objects as arguments, and returns a multi-method object, into which the single-method objects have been packed.

Example:

```
interface MultiMethodInterface {
    void method1();
    String method2(String arg);
}

public static void example() {
    // One lambda for each method, they are packed into a 
    // MultiMethodInterface object by the multiMethodInterface method
    MultiMethodInterface i1 = createMultiMethodObject(
            () -> System.out.println("method1"),
            arg -> "method2: " + arg);

    // Sometimes only one of the methods is used, a specialized wrapper
    // can be used if that is common
    MultiMethodInterface i2 = 
            createMethod1Wrapper(() -> System.out.println("method1"));
}

public static MultiMethodInterface createMultiMethodObject(
        Runnable methodAction1,
        Function<String, String> methodAction2)
{
    return new MultiMethodInterface() {
        @Override
        public void method1() {
            methodAction1.run();
        }
        @Override
        public String method2(String arg) {
            return methodAction2.apply(arg);
        }
    };
}

public static MultiMethodInterface createMethod1Wrapper(Runnable methodAction1) {
    return createMultiMethodObject(methodAction1, arg -> "");
}
```

The resulting code is at least a bit shorter and prettier than to create a anonymous class. At least if the method implementations are short, and/or only one of the methods needs to be implemented.

This technique is used for example in the [SWT toolkit](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FSelectionListener.html&anchor=widgetSelectedAdapter-java.util.function.Consumer-), to create listener objects.

Comment: what if we use parameter as well in method1?

Comment: @RaviParekh: In that case, instead of `Runnable` you can use one of the consumer or function interfaces, for example [`java.util.function.BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html). If you have more than two arguments you have to create your own special purpose interface to substitute `Runnable`.

Comment: @RaviParekh I updated the answer to demonstrate how to handle methods with arguments.