# Passing an instance of Comparable to a method that expects a Comparator

Tags: java, java-8, comparator, comparable, functional-interface

The `Stream` class in Java 8 defines a `max` method that requires a `Comparator` argument. Here is the method signature:

```
Optional<T> max(Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

`Comparator` is a functional interface that has an abstract `compare` method with this signature. Notice `compare` requires 2 arguments.

```
int compare(T o1, T o2)
```

The `Comparable` interface has an abstract `compareTo` method with this signature. Notice `compareTo` requires only 1 argument.

```
int compareTo(T o)
```

In Java 8, the following code works perfectly. However, I expected a compilation error like, "the Integer class does not define compareTo(Integer, Integer)".

```
int max = Stream.of(0, 4, 1, 5).max(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

Can someone help explain why it's possible to pass an instance of `Comparable` to a method that expects an instance of `Comparator` even though their method signatures are not compatible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561614/java-8-streams-min-and-max-why-does-this-compile (you could use `Integer::compare` instead of `Integer::compareTo`)

Comment: You're not passing an Integer instance. You're passing a reference to the method Integer.compareTo(). That's quite different.

Comment: This works perfectly. However, using `Comparator.naturalOrder()` for types implementing `Comparable` is potentially more efficient.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a nice feature about *method references*. Note that `Integer::compareTo` is an *instance method*. You need two `Integer` objects to call it. One on the left side (the target object), and one on the right side (the first and only parameter).

So `Integer::compareTo` is a method reference for a method, that expects two `Integer` objects and returns an `int`. `Comparator<Integer>` is a *functional interface* for functions, that expect two `Integer` objects and return an `int`. That's the reason why it works.

Comment: BTW, `Comparator<? super Integer> compareTo = Integer::compareTo;` also compiles perfectly.

Comment: I see, so `Integer::compareTo` is equivalent to `(a, b) > a.compareTo(b)`?