# continue with if statement java

Tags: java, if-statement, continue

why I can't use continue with The ? : Operator    :

```
public class TestArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  double[] myList = {1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 3.5};

  // Print all the array elements
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(myList[i] + " ");
  }


  // Finding the largest element
  double max = myList[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
     myList[i] > max ? max = myList[i] : continue ;
  }
  System.out.println("Max is " + max);  
}
}
```

Comment: This is not how ternary operators work. They are meant to shorten conditional assignment, rather than condense code paths.

Comment: Ternary if expects a return value, which `continue` does not provide.

Comment: Because that operator expects **expressions** for both cases. Continue is not an expression that can be evaluated to result in a **value**!

Comment: But also, the conditional operator is not a statement expression: even if you had an expression as the third operand, that code would not compile.

Comment: If you don't know how to use ternary operators and get errors. Advice is to learn that first or use if else instead. max = myList[i] > max ? myList[i] : max;

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator does not function like that. It is used to return one of two values depending on a boolean expression.

```
x = statement ? value1 : value2
```

If that is not what you want then use a simple `if else` statement. Just replace with:

```
for (int i = 1; i < myList.length; i++) {
    if(myList[i] > max)
        max = myList[i]
}
```

---

If you want you can also have a look at [`.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Arrays.stream(myList).max()
```

and a bit more on how it works in: [Java 8 stream's .min() and .max(): why does this compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22561614/6400526)

Comment: @datascientist - did this help you understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator works like this method:

```
public static <R> R ternaryOperator(boolean condition, R onTrue, R onFalse) {
    if (condition == true) {
        return onTrue;
    } else {
        return onFalse;
    }
}
```

Do you think you can write something like this?

```
ternaryOperator(myList[i] > max, max = myList[i], continue)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a normal `if` statement because a ternary operator returns a value.