# Java 8 Predicate to select an element from list based on element properties

Tags: java, lambda, predicate, functional-interface

There is a List Employee Objects, each employee object has property start date.
Task is to select only one employee who has the earliest start  date.
I am trying to use Java 8 Predicate for this.
So basically how can I compare list elements with each other in predicate ?
And how can I do the same thing using lambda with Functional interface ?

Comment: you can use terminal function - min/max with your comparator. Take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561614/java-8-streams-min-and-max-why-does-this-compile#)

Comment: could you pls paste here what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Predicates are based on the mathematical concept of a Predicate, which is a function F(x) that returns true or false based on some properties of x. Given that the function cannot be redefined while traversing the collection, it isn't probably the to-go option for finding the minimum or maximum of some Collection.

A recommended way of doing so using Java 8 would be using the `min` function included on Java Streams.

```
Employee oldestEmployee = employees.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getStartDate)).get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have Employee:

```
class Employee {
   private LocalDate startDate;
}
```

Constructor and getter are omitted. You can find the employee with the earliest startDate as follows:

```
Optional<Employee> min = list.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getStartDate));
```