# Java 8 stream max() function argument type Comparator vs Comparable

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wrote some simple code like below. This class works fine without any errors.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        int value = intList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();

        //int value = intList.stream().max(<Comparator<? super T> comparator type should pass here>).get();

        System.out.println("value :"+value);
    }
}
```

As the code comment shows the `max()` method should pass an argument of type `Comparator<? super Integer>`.

But `Integer::compareTo` implements `Comparable` interface - **not** `Comparator`.

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
    public int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) {
        return compare(this.value, anotherInteger.value);
    }
}
```

How can this work? The `max()` method says it needs a `Comparator` argument, but it works with `Comparable` argument.

I know I have misunderstood something, but I do now know what. Can someone please explain?

Comment: `Integer::compareTo` does not return a Comparable - it is the short definition for: "Please compiler generate a matching implementation for the type that is needed (in this case `Comparator`) and map the arguments to the specified function." In this case the function requires two "arguments" (`this` and the one parameter of `compareTo`) and the Comparator provides two arguments -> works.

Comment: *""Please compiler, generate..."* ... compilers always respond best to politeness and courtesy :-)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561614/java-8-streams-min-and-max-why-does-this-compile

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
int value = intList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

The above snippet of code is logically equivalent to the following:

```
int value = intList.stream().max((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)).get();
```

Which is also logically equivalent to the following:

```
int value = intList.stream().max(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}).get();
```

`Comparator` is a functional interface and can be used as a lambda or method reference, which is why your code compiles and executes successfully.

I recommend reading [Oracle's tutorial on Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (they use an example where two objects are compared) as well as the Java Language Specification on [§15.13. Method Reference Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) to understand why this works.

Comment: Although it's absolutely correct, it doesn't answer "How can this work?"

Answer (score 17):

I can relate to your confusion.

We've got a `Comparator`'s method which declares two parameters

```
int compare(T o1, T o2);
```

and we've got an `Integer`'s method which takes one parameter

```
int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger)
```

How on earth does `Integer::compareTo` get resolved to a `Comparator` instance?

When a method reference points to **an instance method**,  the parser can look for methods with arity `n-1` (`n` is the expected number of parameters).

<sup>Here's an excerpt from the JLS on how applicable methods are identified. I will drop the first part about parsing the expression preceding the `::` token.</sup>

> Second, given a targeted function type with `n` parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:
>
> If the method reference expression has the form `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the potentially applicable methods are:
>
> - the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable (§15.12.2.1) for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression; plus
> - the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable for a method invocation which **names `Identifier`, has arity n-1, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression**.
>
> **Two different arities, `n` and `n-1`, are considered, to account for the possibility that this form refers to either a static method or an instance method.**
>
> ...
>
> A method reference expression of the form `ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier` can be interpreted in different ways. If `Identifier` refers to an instance method, then **the implicit lambda expression has an extra parameter** compared to if `Identifier` refers to a static method.
>
> <sup>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1</sup>

If we were to write an implicit lambda expression from that method reference, the first (implicit) parameter would be an instance to call the method on, the second (explicit) parameter would be an argument to pass in the method.

```
(implicitParam, anotherInteger) -> implicitParam.compareTo(anotherInteger)
```

Note that a method reference differs from a lambda expression, even though the former can be easily transformed into the latter. A lambda expression needs to be [desugared](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) into a new method, while a method reference *usually* requires only loading a corresponding constant method handle.

> `Integer::compareTo` implements `Comparable` interface - not `Comparator`.

`Integer::compareTo` as an expression doesn't implement any interface. However, it can refer to/represent different functional types, one of which is `Comparator<Integer>`.

```
Comparator<Integer> a = Integer::compareTo;
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> b = Integer::compareTo;
ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer> c = Integer::compareTo;
```

Answer (score 11):

`Integer` implements `Comparable` by overriding `compareTo`.

That overriden `compareTo`, however, can be used in a way that satisfies and implements the `Comparator` interface.

In its usage here

```
int value = intList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get();
```

it's translated to something like

```
int value = intList.stream().max(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}).get();
```

A method reference (or lambda expression) must satisfy the signature of the corresponding functional interface's single abstract method and, in this case (`Comparator`), `compareTo` does.

---

The idea is that `max` expects a `Comparator` and its `compare` method expects two `Integer` objects. `Integer::compareTo` can satisfy those expectations because it also expects two `Integer` objects. The first is its receiver (the instance on which the method is to be called) and the second is the argument. With the new Java 8 syntax, the compiler translates one style to the other.

(`compareTo` also returns an `int` as required by `Comparator#compare`.)

Comment: Underrated but I think this is the best explanation.

Answer (score 3):

**First trick:** all *instance methods* actually take 1 additional implicit argument, the one you refer to as `this` in method body. E.g.:

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer> {
    public int compareTo(/* Integer this, */ Integer anotherInteger) {
        return compare(this.value, anotherInteger.value);
    }
}

Integer a = 10, b = 100;
int compareResult            = a.compareTo(b);
// this actually 'compiles' to Integer#compareTo(this = a, anotherInteger = b)
```

**Second trick:** Java compiler can "transform" the signature of a method reference to some *functional interface*, if the number and types of arguments (including `this`) satisfy:

```
interface MyInterface {
    int foo(Integer bar, Integer baz);
}

Integer a = 100, b = 1000;

int result1 =                   ((Comparator<Integer>) Integer::compareTo).compare(a, b);
int result2 = ((BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>) Integer::compareTo).apply(a, b);
int result3 =                           ((MyInterface) Integer::compareTo).foo(a, b);

// result1 == result2 == result3
```

As you can see `class Integer` implements none of `Comparator`, `BiFunction` or a random `MyInterface`, but that doesn't stop you from casting the `Integer::compareTo` method reference as those interfaces.