# how could "max" of stream accept param like "Integer::compareTo"

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, parameters, java-stream

The [`Stream.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) takes an argument of type `Comparator`, which contains the `compare()` method; The compare method takes two arguments and returns an `int`. So we can use a method to refer to [`Integer#compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) as an argument to the `max()` method; But [`Integer.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo-java.lang.Integer-) accepts only one parameter, which does not match the number of parameters of the `compare()` method, so why can it also be used as a parameter of `max()`?

that's my code:

```java
Integer maxMenuTp = menuTpList.stream().max(Integer::compareTo);
```

Comment: `Integer::compareTo`, when implementing `Comparator`, is equivalent to `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)`.

Comment: can you provide some more infomation, such as what your menuTpList looks like, or some more code, etc.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Java 8 stream max() function argument type Comparator vs Comparable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55694015/6395627).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer::compareTo` i.e. `public int compareTo(Integer b)` in `Integer` is an **instance** method, therefore it fits the `Comparator` functional interface by accepting one parameter as `this`, and the second as the method parameter.

Therefore `(a, b) -> Comparator.compare(a, b)` and `(a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)` are both acceptable as lambda parameters.